# Komparator 4 No files shown

Tags: 16.04

I guess I'm just too stupid. But as I can't find any solution:
I installed Komparator4 on 16.04. Never mind, which directories I choose to compare, always the are no results shown in the display.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bug is actually exists.

I [reported it to launchpad as bug 1730178](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1730178) from clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.

> Steps to reproduce:
>   1. Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS / 17.10 / 18.04 LTS
>   2. Install komparator package
>   3. Create folder with duplicates and launch duplicates search here:
>
> ```
> mkdir /tmp/komp
> cp /etc/os-release /tmp/komp/
> cp /etc/os-release /tmp/komp/os-release2
> komparator4 /tmp/komp/ /tmp/komp/
> ```
>
> 4. Do not touch options in komparator4 window and click *Search* button.

On my machines which were upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS I have no problems with komparator.

I'm sorry, but I have no solution for clean installations.

---

Possible solutions:

- On clean installation it works on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
- Use other program *FSlint Janitor* from *fslint* package as alternative to komparator4.

Comment: I tried before already and tried again right now - same result. I'm really frustated.

Comment: Try the following: open terminal, `mkdir /tmp/komp`, `cp /etc/os-release /tmp/komp/ `, `cp /etc/os-release /tmp/komp/os-release2`, `komparator4 /tmp/komp/ /tmp/komp/`, in komparator4 window click *Search* button, you should see one item in *Duplicate files*.

Comment: No results. Do I have to install any additional packages but komparator4? Komparator4 works on KDE, Ubuntu uses Unity desktop.  Any Kioslave-tools et.?

Comment: I simply did `sudo apt-get install komparator` and got 4:1.0-2 installed. I tried to remove its config files with `rm ~/.kde/share/config/komparator4*` and did my test from comment above. It shows search results as before. You may try to reinstall komparator with `sudo apt-get install komparator --reinstall` and check system for broking packages. On my system the following KIO packages are installed: *kio, libkf5kiocore5, libkf5kiofilewidgets5, libkf5kiontlm5, libkf5kiowidgets5, libkio5*. I'm using amd64 OS.

Comment: I tried it all - no success. It's very strange. I am using ubuntu 16.04 on a desktop 64 and ubuntu 17.10 on a laptop 64. Both systems show the same behavior of komparator4 (1.0-3 - btw).

Comment: Let's compare the settings: *Basic Search Options* tab - in *Search Options* checked *Include subdirectories*, *Include hidden items* and *Case sensitive search*; in *Duplicate Files Search Options* - checked *Ignore empty files*, *Size comparison* and *Calculate MD5 checksum*;  *Extended Search Options* tab *File Name contains* `*` *and not* (empty), *(none)*, 0, *KB*, *Modified or created* - *any*.

Comment: Also you can try to reinstall some packages with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall kde-runtime kdelibs-bin` for kio_trash and kbuildsycoca4.

Comment: I installed Komparaor4 on a freshly installed ubuntu 17.04 on a desktop and ubuntu 17.10 on a laptop as well. Both show same behaviour.

Comment: You are using Komparator4 too, right? Which Linux version do you use?

Comment: Bug really exists, see my updated answer. I'm sorry for long non-productive chat.

Comment: Obviously it's a bug / incompatibility 16.xx up. This morning I tried with 12.04 - works fine.

Comment: You can use other program *FSlint Janitor* from `fslint` package as alternative to komparator4.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. As the bug made me curious, I'm going to install 12.04 with Komp4. Then update to 14.04, 16.04, 17.04 and see, what will happen. Second try is installing 12.04, updating all steps to 17.10 and then install Komp4.

Comment: FIY: I tested clean installation of 14.04, komparator works here. So you do not need 12.04 (it is unsupported). Now I'm trying to install 14.04 with komparator, then update it to 16.04. I'm going to compare the resulting system with clean installation of 16.04.

Comment: OK, I'll skip 12.04. Instead I'll install Komp4 on 14.04 and then update to 16.10, 17.04 and finally 17.10 to see, if Komp4 will run on all of the later Ubuntu versions.

Comment: It does not work on 17.10 and 18.04 (I have already tested). On my other 16.04 machine it does not work too.  I have sent e-mail to komp4 developer with our question.